# SwiftUI Disclosure Group Text Alignment

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui

Is there a way to prevent wrapped text in a `DisclouseGroup` title from being center aligned?

[image: Disclosure group with center aligned text]

I have tried to add the following, but neither approach has been effective:

```swift
DisclosureGroup("A really long disclosure group title that is being center aligned.", isExpanded: false) {
   ...
}
.multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
```

```swift
DisclosureGroup("A really long disclosure group title that is being center aligned.", isExpanded: false) {
   ...
}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Label initialiser for DisclosureGroup. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup/init(isexpanded:content:label:))

Here is a working example.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var isExpanded = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                Text("This is some text")
            } label: {
                Text("A really long disclosure group title that is being center aligned.")
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This gives the following output

[image]

Tested Xcode 14 beta 4 iOS 16 Simulator

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a Form or a List:

```
struct DisclosureAligning: View {

    @State var isExpanded = false

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            DisclosureGroup("A really long disclosure group title that is being center aligned.", isExpanded: $isExpanded) {
                Text("text")
            }
        }
    }
}
```